# How to select range of elements by Id Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<p>
    <span id='0'>Đầu</span>
    <span id='1'>tiên</span>
    <span id='2'>xin</span>
    <span id='3'>khẳng</span>
    <span id='4'>định</span>
    <span id='5'>cái</span>
    <span id='6'>chuyện</span>
</p>
```

I want to select spans have id 2 to 5. I want to wrapAll() them by a `<span class="wrap">`

```
$("seletedspans").wrapAll("<span class="wrap"></span")
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are ordered then try

```
$('#2').nextUntil('#6').addBack().wrapAll('<span class="wrap"></span')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mv5xU/)

Comment: it's not runing. Can you help me!

Comment: @LêVănThành did you check the attached fiddle... try to recreate your problem there

Comment: Wow, this is... deep jQ. Me gusta :)